# "has always fascinated" vs "always fascinates"

Tags: present-perfect, present-simple

> Science **has always fascinated** him.

As I understand it, this phrase "always + fascinate" is very commonly used with Present/Past Perfect. I can't understand why if we have the Present Simple's keyword.

Science always fascinates him. - Is this a mistaken sentence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are good: they have slightly different meanings.

*Science fascinates him* says what's the case now, but nothing about the past. Perhaps he was never interested in science until recently.

*Science has always fascinated him* talks about the past up to the present. It says nothing about the present.

Normally we will assume that he is still fascinated, but that implication can be overridden (eg *Science has always fascinated him, but since he became ill he has lost interst in it.*).

Comment: Quite right. If I tell my ex-partner I always cook, she might ask, "Since when?" If I tell her I've always cooked she may call me an infernal liar.

Comment: Btw, I think you left out "always" from your second sentence.

Comment: @Colin Fine, In this case what tense is better to use if I need to talk about this fascination from his childhood and also emphasize the actuality of it in these days (and maybe always in his life until he lives)? Present Perfect?

Comment: @Sergei: yes, _he has always been fascinated_ conveys that. (I put it in the passive before going back and reading your original: I think the passive is slightly more idiomatic here, perhaps because it makes him the subject, rather than science. Your active sentence is OK too.)